# Injective function with a bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was studying Real  Analysis and found the following problem.It was part of a admission test for doctorate degree of my university:

Prove or give a counterexample: if $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is a differentiable function such that $f^{'}$ is a bounded function, then there exists $c \in \mathbb R$ such that the function $$g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R  $$ $$ g(x)=f(x)+cx$$ is injective.

I didn't understand what the fact of a function has a bounded derivative has to do with $f$ be injective or not. What I thought is that if $f$ is injective, so take $c=0$. If not, take $c=1$

Comment: *Hint:* A function with a positive derivative is injective.

Comment: Counterexample to $c=1$: take $f(x) = 100\cos(x)$. Then $g(x) = 100\cos(x) + x$ is not injective since $g(0) > 0, g(\pi) < 0, g(2\pi) > 0,$ and $g(3\pi) < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injective means $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}, ~g(x)=g(y)\Longrightarrow x=y$

therefore,

$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}, ~g(x)=g(y)\Longrightarrow f(x)+cx=f(y)+cy \Longrightarrow f(x)-f(y)=-c(x-y)$

By Mean Value Theorem,

$$\exists \xi\in (x,y), f(x)-f(y)=f'(\xi)(x-y)$$

we get

$$ -c(x-y)=f'(\xi)(x-y)$$

Since $|f'(\xi)|\le M$ is bounded, if we choose $c$, such that $|c|>M$, then we get

$$x=y$$

hence, $g$ is injective.